# Trigonometric tough limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I am still struggling with this one. Can't figure it out...

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$$

I tried $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2{x}}$

Comment: Apply L'Hôpital's rule twice

Comment: You could also use $1 - \cos(x) = 2\sin^2(x/2)$

Comment: Or multiply top and bottom by $1 + \cos x$.

Comment: Or use the Taylor expansion: $1-\cos(x) = \dfrac {x^2}{2} + O(x^4)$

Comment: If you put in $\cos x= \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$, then the fraction becomes $(1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x})/x^2$.  Multiply the numerator and denominator by $(1+\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x})$, apply difference of squares to simplify the product in the numerator, and then you can apply the $(\sin x)/x\to 1$ limit.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac{(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x))}{x^2(1+\cos(x))}=.....$$