# Find the range of $\frac{x^2}{2(1-\cos x)}$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: functions

Find the range of $$f(x) =\frac{x^2}{2(1-\cos x)}$$ for $$0<x<1$$

I tried to solve by writing $x$ in terms of $y,$ but no result.

Comment: Can we find range by check lim at 0+

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @Alv range$\ne$domain

Comment: You can see the function monotonically increases if you check its derivative

Comment: @Alv you r right but how to find range

Comment: Someone has noted that you can see it is monotonically increasing if you take a derivative, if you are not familiar with derivatives you could also note that it can be expressed as the product of two monotonically increasing functions, $$ x^2 $$ and $$ \frac{1}{1-cos(x)} $$ so it is itself a monotonically increasing function

Comment: I checked it's derivative yes it's a increasing function

Comment: Can we find it by taking limit?by       rationalising denominator

Comment: @Carlyle $\frac1{1-\cos x}$ is decreasing for $0<x<\pi.$

Comment: @ShreyashBindal [$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256117)

Comment: @AnneBauval you are right. For x =$2\pi{n}$ where $n\in{Z}$. Function has undefined values.

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry, my mistake

Comment: it's two applications of l'Hopital's rule

Comment: @MaximusFastidiousIrreverence L'Hopital is but one of the [many ways to prove this limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818000).

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{xg(x)}{2\left(1-\cos x\right)^2}$ where $g(x)=2\left(1-\cos x\right)-x\sin x.$

From $g(0)=0$ and $\forall x\in(0,\pi/2)\quad g'(x)=\cos x\left(\tan x-x\right)>0,$ we derive that $f$ is increasing on its domain $(0,1).$ By continuity, its range is therefore
$$(\lim_0f,\lim_1f)=\left(1,\frac1{2\left(1-\cos 1\right)}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq10r.jpg)

Can we solve it like this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Of course we can: this is exaclty the method in the link I gave in comment 13min ago. But this should be a comment, not an answer, unless [you complete it with a full solution of your problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). The main difficulty is not this limit. It is to prove that $f'>0.$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that this function is monotonic at this range, and then calculate:
$f(1)=\frac{1}{2(1-cos(1))}, \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1$, and so this is the range.